# .NET Application looking for DLLs in locale specific sub-folder

Tags: .net, dll, locale, app-config, subdirectory

My company have some internal utility libraries containing things like base services, useful extension methods etc.

I have recently completely re-written these from the ground up and have packaged them as nu-get packages, hosted on our internal network.

When I've added added a NuGet reference to the packages in a project, the application will build, but sometimes when debugging or running it will fail saying that the libraries cannot be found. This seems to be entirely at random, and usually if I re-build and re-deploy the problem will be temporally fixed.

A colleague of mine managed to narrow down the problem by running process monitor, and found that the application was looking for the files to be in bin/en-GB/{MyCompany.DllName}/{MyCompany.DllName}.dll when the file was actually in bin/{MyCompany.DllName}.dll, as I would expect by default.

So as a temporary fix, we can add the folder structure it requires and are able to run the application, but having to re-add the folder structure and manually copy and paste dlls around after every clean/rebuild is not a long term solution. I also don't know:

1. Why it sometimes works.
2. What is causing this behavior.

I don't know whether the issue is with the utility libraries project, nuget package, or the consuming project.

I realise this is probably some helpful by design .NET feature, allowing locale specific versions of ddls, but in this situation I do not require them, and the dll can be/is culture invariant.

Any help would be massively appreciated as it is holding up the release of our new libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism in .NET that makes it look for assemblies that contain code in an "en-GB" subdirectory like that.  It is only ever used for satellite assemblies, they don't contain code, only resources, and it is the ResourceManager class that does the probing.

The only somewhat likely candidate for this kind of behavior is an improper AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event handler in the application.  An event that's going to run if your assembly cannot be found for some reason.  Search the codebase for "AssemblyResolve", it usually hovers near the Main() method.

A long-distance shot is the [AssemblyCulture] attribute.  It must be "neutral" for assemblies that contains code.  I *think* that might affect where Fusion probes when it can't find the assembly in the normal location.  That should be fixed, but the core problem is still that it can't find your assembly.

Do watch out for [AssemblyVersion], if you deploy libraries with NuGet then you often also need an app.exe.config with a `<bindingRedirect>` so an update of your library doesn't break the app.  Never use, say, "1.0.*", that always causes misery.

And use [Fuslogvw.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to diagnose load failures like this.  If these hints don't solve your problem then show us the trace you get.

Comment: Yup, I accidentally set assembly culture :S. Thanks for that. I'm an idiot.